# Google Earth Engine - remove layer from the layer manager

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a way in Google Earth Engine to remove layers which are in the layer manager?

Example:

```js
//Image selection
var img1 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20161231T035142_20161231T040436_T47PNP')

//Location
var center = ee.Geometry.Point(99.256, 12.1682)
Map.addLayer(center,'','Center')
Map.centerObject(center,10);

//color palette
var rgb_vis = {min:0, max:3000, bands:['B4','B3','B2']};

//add images to map
Map.addLayer(img1,rgb_vis,'Image 1',true);

//NDVI Button
var button = ui.Button({
  label: 'Calculate NDVI',
  onClick: function() {
    var NDVIimg1 = img1.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
    Map.addLayer(NDVIimg1,'','NDVI',true)
  }
});
print(button);
```

I would like to get rid of the layer "Image 1" in the layer manager, but the centerpoint should stay. Is there a better way than put a Map.clear() in the button code and re-add the centerpoint again?

```js
//NDVI Button
var button = ui.Button({
  label: 'Calculate NDVI',
  onClick: function() {
    Map.clear()
    var NDVIimg1 = img1.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
    Map.addLayer(center,'','Center')
    Map.addLayer(NDVIimg1,'','NDVI',true)
  }
});
print(button);
```

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```js
var removeLayer = function(name) {
  var layers = Map.layers()
  // list of layers names
  var names = []
  layers.forEach(function(lay) {
    var lay_name = lay.getName()
    names.push(lay_name)
  })
  // get index
  var index = names.indexOf(name)
  if (index > -1) {
    // if name in names
    var layer = layers.get(index)
    Map.remove(layer)
  } else {
    print('Layer '+name+' not found')
  }
}
```

It's available in [geetools](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor):

```js
// import tools
tools = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:tools')

// use function
tools.removeLayer(name)
```

Comment: Thanks :D I wasn't fully aware of the Map.remove() function or how to transfer it to layers.

Comment: can't u just remove them in forEach directly? why all this name rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple:

```js
// create a function to remove layer using index
function removelay(){
  
  var lay = Map.layers().get(1);
  if(lay){
  Map.remove(lay)}

  else{print('layer missing')}
}

//NDVI Button
var button = ui.Button({
  label: 'Calculate NDVI',
  onClick: function() {
    removelay()  // add the new function to the onClick callback
    var NDVIimg1 = img1.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
    Map.addLayer(NDVIimg1,'','NDVI',true)
  }
});
print(button);
```